# Google Alerts web API for Python?

Tags: python, asp.net-web-api, google-alerts

Google web APIs have a [Python library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/). [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) has an email and an RSS feed.

Does anyone know of an automated way to add Google Alerts through a web API in Python? That is, without clicking.

Note: [the related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860442/google-alerts-api) doesn't answer the web API question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is galerts http://pypi.python.org/pypi/galerts.

It has the ability to add and manage alerts and subscriptions directly from python.

Answer (score 4):

`galerts` is obsoleted.

There is still a working alternative:

google-alerts: https://pypi.org/project/google-alerts/