# Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?

Tags: php, cookies, curl, session-cookies

I have this code for logging into Google using Simple DOM Parser with curl. I've tried adding in the cookiejar file, but to no avail. I keep getting the message:

*Your browser's cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on.*

Any idea on how to solve this?

Here's my code for reference:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&service=alerts&continue=http://www.google.com/alerts/manage');

//... some code for getting post data here

$curl_connection = curl_init('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);  
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
curl_close($curl_connection);

echo $result;
```

Comment: You should probably fetch the URL in the `file_get_html` function using cURL instead as it probably sets some cookies the the auth service may be looking form.  Also, can you confirm the file specified by `COOKIEJAR` is being created and contains cookies?

Comment: I checked the COOKIEJAR file, yep it contains some text inside. I also set the curl_init url to the same url as file_get_html, still the same thing, no cookie for me. :(

Comment: I do get some headers here, does that matter? Here they are: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Set-Cookie: GoogleAccountsLocale_session=en; Secure Set-Cookie: GAPS=1:ZuuFm50cJM2_fiqQc38hkyuCjZXRRg:bMuhAssScKIBtI1L;Path=/;Expires=Thu, 23-Jan-2014 18:32:24 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2012 18:32:24 GMT Expires: Tue, 24 Jan 2012 18:32:24 GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Content-Length: 1848 Server: GSE

Comment: They are okay, but it is setting some coookies that should be saved for the next request.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is some modified code that works.

It first requests the login page to get the initial cookies and extract the required values for the login form.  Next it performs a post to the login service.  It then checks to see if it is trying to use javascript and meta tags to redirect to the destination URL.

It seemed like you already have code for grabbing the form fields, so I didn't post mine, but if you need it let me know.  Just make sure `$formFields` is an associative array with keys being the field name, and the value being the field value.

```
<?php

/**
 * Log in to Google account and go to account page
 *
 */

$USERNAME = 'youraccount@gmail.com';
$PASSWORD = 'password';
$COOKIEFILE = 'cookies.txt';

// initialize curl handle used for all requests
$ch = curl_init();

// set some options on the handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $COOKIEFILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $COOKIEFILE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

// url of our first request fetches the account login page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
  'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&service=alerts&continue=http://www.google.com/alerts/manage');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// extract form fields from account login page
$formFields = getFormFields($data);

// inject email and password into form
$formFields['Email']  = $USERNAME;
$formFields['Passwd'] = $PASSWORD;
unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

$post_string = http_build_query($formFields); // build urlencoded POST string for login

// set url to login page as a POST request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

// execute login request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// check for "Redirecting" message in title to indicate success
// based on your language - you may need to change this to match some other string
if (strpos($result, '<title>Redirecting') === false) {
    die("Login failed");
    var_dump($result);
}

// login likely succeeded - request account page; unset POST so we do a regular GET
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://myaccount.google.com/?utm_source=OGB');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);

// execute request for login page using our cookies
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;


// helpef functions below

// find google "#gaia_loginform" for logging in
function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form.*?id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        die('didnt find login form');
    }
}

// extract all <input fields from a form
function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}
```

Comment: Whoa! Thanks for this! I tried it out though and I get a Login Failed. Just plugged in my post_data array to your formFields array. Here's the string: continue=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Falerts%2Fmanage&service=alerts&dsh=-6553802846829809996&hl=en&GALX=Cg4XgqEmZ_w&timeStmp=&secTok=&Email=xxxxxxxx&Passwd=xxxxxxxxxxx&signIn=Sign+in&rmShown=1
After failing, there's no other output.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, thanks!:D I will try to see what made yours work and mine not work.

Comment: It looks okay assuming it was passed to the right variable for curl.  I just updated the code with the full version that grabs the hidden fields.  Input your username and password there and see if it works for you.  I just confirmed again the whole example works.  If login fails, it should var_dump the resulting webpage.

Comment: Ok I see you got it working now,  Nice job.  Either way the example now contains the functions for grabbing the hidden fields.

Comment: I got it to work, it's because my post_data lacked some data I guess, so I rewrote it again with regards to the results of the first curl request and that made it work! Thanks so much, this was a lot of help.:)

Comment: Hi! Just in case anybody stumbles upon this thread, it looks like Google changed the way it redirects the page after success so the line `if (strpos($result, '<title>Redirecting') === false)`was always returning false (at least for me) although the script was working fine. I just omitted that line and it works fine. Also I replaced the constat COOKIEJAR with a filename. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: i stumbled 1 whole day with that line. :( .. just figured it out 10 mins ago. any way this post is great :)

Comment: it's not working , giving this Message  'didnt find login form.'