# Is there any software for automatic application uploading for Android Market developers?

Tags: android, google-play

Does exist some software for developers that is able to upload applications into Android Market (Google Play)? I want to automate this process, because I have very many apps in Market. Official or unofficial, no matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has presented a new API to work with Google Play Developer Console. Here is the link for it's description: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

Answer (score 2):

The API (http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) here is for emulating the android marketplace to pull data. You'd have to mimick the login onto the android marketplace developer center then use some kind of DOM Crawler like (symphony dom crawler to navigate and use GET/POST to mimick the calls for uploading).

[Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any official API that allows this. I doubt Google would be keen to implement it as it could encourage submission of vast numbers of auto-generated apps.

The nearest I've seen is this unofficial API to read data, but as far as I'm aware there's no facility to submit apps:
http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Comment: Of course - good point about the "vast numbers of auto-generated apps".