# Unable to login Google with curl

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I want to login in google.com with php via `curl` but i am getting login page again and again.

Here is my code

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.1    (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.79 Safari/537.1 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, COOKIEJAR);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Also it is not creating the cookie file

I found this link [Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off) . there is also the same code as mine but also i am unable to login.

What is wrong in this code ?

Comment: I doubt google wants you interacting with their pages like that. They probably have security against it. Use cURL as google documents it: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL

Comment: @UjjwalManandhar Check the answer to the question you referenced.  It is updated and works for logging into Google again.

Comment: @drew010 : It is not working. I think you have added the cookie filename. the problem is cookie file is not being generated too and its not working at all again @ least in machine? what might be the problem ?

Comment: I made that change but also changed the code that finds the login form and fields, that was the real problem.  It's also important that you make sure `$COOKIEFILE` is writable so it can actually save the cookies.

Comment: @drew010 : thank got that too. my cookie folder is writable but for some reason i cannot see the cookie file. I have checked the php configuration and also the httpd.conf file , all are okay :(. thank for the help