# Ingress Login Error

Tags: php, curl

Same Question: [Login to Google Ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435645/login-to-google-ingress/25632294#25632294)

I attempted to comment there, and it was deleted.... not good monitoring.

I am trying to login with PHP, they have a solution there that ALMOST works, but not quite.  the first solution logs into Google Auth fine it appears, but the page that loads the Ingress page still always just says "Sign In"

How can we modify the code to do a complete correct login?

Thanks!

```
<?php
$username = 'email@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';
$cookies = 'cookies.txt';

function getFormFields($data) {
        if(preg_match('/(<form.*?id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
                $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);
                return $inputs;
        } else {
                die('didnt find login form');
        }
}

function getInputs($form) {
        $inputs = array();
        $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

        if($elements > 0) {
                for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
                        $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);
                        if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                                $name  = $name[1];
                                $value = '';
                                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                                        $value = $value[1];
                                }
                                $inputs[$name] = $value;
                        }
                }
        }
        return $inputs;
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.56 Safari/537.17");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookies);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttp://www.ingress.com/intel');
$data = curl_exec($ch);

$formFields = getFormFields($data);
$formFields['Email']  = $username;
$formFields['Passwd'] = $password;
unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

$post_string = '';
foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
        $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
}
$post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.ingress.com/intel');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;

curl_close($ch);
@unlink($cookies);
?>
```