# Open google calendar with auto login

Tags: php

Open google calendar with auto login

Requiremment: We want to facility to open a the google calendar with gmail id and pwd without the intervention of the user.So basically it will log out any other user if logged in to google and auto login with provided email and pwd and show the google calendar.

I have already tried following things,

1) Google calendar embed script:   It does not log the user to the
    google if already not logged in and uses which ever the logged in
    users google calendar.

2) Google calendar API:    The google service
    API allows auto authenticate to specific google service account and
    then we can fetch the events but this authentication does not
    actually logs the user to google a/c so we cannot show the google
    calendar.

3) Oauth2 authentication:  This forces login but we cannot provide
    email/pwd automatically here.

4) php curl login to google:   I have
    checked php curl login to google but it is not working and it is no
    more supported (deprecated) by google.
ref:
[Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off)

```
      Is there any other option to achieve this.
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be possible.  Google won't allow it.  Really, having to know a user's username and password is a bad idea security-wise anyway.  Even if you had this, there are circumstances where it isn't going to work... two factor authentication for example.