# How to create new google alert delivering it to feed, using PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, google-api-client, google-alerts

All i need - it is create google alert connected to my account, which should be delivered to my feed.
For auth i'm using curl

```
function googleAuthenticate($username, $password, $source, $service = 'alerts') {
$session_token = $source . '_' . $service . '_auth_token';

if (isset($_SESSION[$session_token])) {
    echo 'уже есть';
    return $_SESSION[$session_token];
}

// get an authorization token
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
$post_fields = "accountType=" . urlencode('HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE')
    . "&Email=" . urlencode($username)
    . "&Passwd=" . urlencode($password)
    . "&source=" . urlencode($source)
    . "&service=" . urlencode($service);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if (strpos($response, '200 OK') === false) {
    return false;
}

// find the auth code
preg_match("/(Auth=)([\w|-]+)/", $response, $matches);
if (!$matches[2]) {
    return false;
}

$_SESSION[$session_token] = $matches[2];
return $matches[2];}
```

but i couldn't fill form on google.com/alerts

Comment: You need to provide more details about the issue if you want help.

Answer (score 3):

Based on code from this page:

[Login to Google with PHP and Curl, Cookie turned off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991873/login-to-google-with-php-and-curl-cookie-turned-off)

```
function createAlert($search) {

        $USERNAME = 'EMAIL_ADDRESS';
        $PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD';
        $COOKIEFILE = 'cookies.txt';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $COOKIEFILE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $COOKIEFILE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
        'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&service=alerts&continue=http://www.google.com/alerts/manage');
        $data = curl_exec($ch);

        $formFields = $this->getFormFields($data);

        $formFields['Email']  = $USERNAME;
        $formFields['Passwd'] = $PASSWORD;
        unset($formFields['PersistentCookie']);

        $post_string = '';
        foreach($formFields as $key => $value) {
        $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
        }

        $post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        if (strpos($result, '<title>Redirecting') === false) {
            var_dump($result);
            die("Login failed");
        } else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/alerts');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, null);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            // Create alert

            preg_match('/<input type="hidden" name="x" value="([^"]+)"/', $result, $matches);

            $post = array(
                "x" => $matches[1],     // anti-XSRF key
                "q" => $search,     // Search term  
                "t" => 7,       // Result type (everything)
                "f" => 1,       // Frequency (once a day)
                "l" => 1,       // How many (all results)
                "e" => "feed"       // Type of delivery (RSS)
            );

            $post_string = '';

            foreach($post as $key => $value) {
                $post_string .= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
            }

            $post_string = substr($post_string, 0, -1);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/alerts/create');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $matches = array();
            preg_match('#<a href="(http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/[\d/]+)"#', $result, $matches);

            $top_alert = $matches[1];

            return $top_alert;
        }
    }


    function getFormFields($data)
    {
        if (preg_match('/(<form.*?id=.?gaia_loginform.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
            $inputs = $this->getInputs($matches[1]);

            return $inputs;
        } else {
            die("didn't find login form");
        }
    }

    function getInputs($form)
    {
        $inputs = array();

        $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

        if ($elements > 0) {
            for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
                $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

                if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                    $name  = $name[1];
                    $value = '';

                    if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                        $value = $value[1];
                    }

                    $inputs[$name] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return $inputs;
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error, `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\stocks\galerts.php on line 25`. Line 25 is `$formFields = $this->getFormFields($data);` So I took out the two `$this->` references in the code, but now I get `Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\stocks\galerts.php on line 59`. Line 59 is `"x" => $matches[1],`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lib: http://coders11.com/googlealertsapi/

It recently became commercial, but it works very well:

> Last update: 11/02/2014 We are not sharing this class anymore. You can
>   buy the full source code with commercial license without limits for
>   €59 / $83

Comment: @MarcoZen well, the library I linked still works, but it's no longer free.

Comment: Anybody used this code before ? Does it really work ?

Comment: @MarcoZen I currently use it and it works without problems. It's just a small 300 lines class. I'm not sure if it worths the 60€ but well, if you don't want to develop it yourself it's ok.

Comment: MazarD -> Thanks...plan to get it.