# Google API for Real Time Information?

Tags: api, google-api, real-time-updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Alerts API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860442/google-alerts-api)

Does Google have an API for streaming real time updates on a website? For example, let's say I want a website stream in real time about "green apples" as soon as they appear in Google? I've looked through the API's but am not sure if any of these provide the functionality.