# Google alerts Post parameters

Tags: c#, post, cookies, sessionid

I am trying to automate google alerts.I am using c# to do this,I found out that there are certain parameters that need to be "Posted" in order to create an alert successfully.I am pasting those here:-

```
x:AMJHsmXPXoR-3tIdZfsQJXzLJEI55G189A:1337777808728

q:test

t:7

f:1

l:0

e:abc@gmail.com
```

q:is the name of the search string for which I want the alert.

e:is my email id

I can't figure out what others are for. Can you suggest something?especially x I have a suspicion that it is really important :)

Edit:-

I need to automate the creation of alerts so I will need to post the data every-time I create a new alert.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860442/google-alerts-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an API for google alerts.

This has already been asked on so:
[Google Alerts API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860442/google-alerts-api)

The accepted answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/860927/444610).

It sounds like you can just consume an RSS feed, but it doesn't sound like you can post anything.

Comment: Yeah I already saw that but the thing is I need to automate the creation of alerts.So I will need to post the data in the format I described above.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok so I think that I have got the answer.These parameters are hidden input types on the form element in the source of the page.I should have checked that earlier.They can easily be extracted from the source using a method that you are comfortable with, regex or html agility,and can be posted to obtain the result.


I hope this helps someone who is looking to automate the creation of google alerts.I will post the full code once I test it completely.


Thanks for taking time to read this post. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [c# lib api to read, create and delete google alerts](http://coders11.com/googlealertsapi).

The downside is that it recently became commercial.