# Creating a plagiarism detector using google search appliance api

Tags: google-api

i wish to design an application that can detect plagiarism ( web based ) in all formats using Google search engine API.
what are the resources that i would be requiring for such an application. 
Basically a user can upload a file and that file would be checked against various formats on the web . i have read that there are web crawlers but how exactly do we use them.
Is Google search appliance API the correct approach?

Also I have not used a Google API before so what would be the best way to start?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.google.com/alerts will do? There are libraries with which you can do a single find, for example in Ruby that would be (at the first glance) a [galerts](https://github.com/amalhotra/galerts) gem. In Python a [galerts](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/galerts/0.1.5) package may help you to manage feeds. Other languages probably have similar libs. After that, [parse result feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860442/google-alerts-api) by yourself.